# Ampersand in sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite, ampersand

How to construct sqlite query containing ampersand in filter:

```
SELECT id FROM mediainfo WHERE album="Betty & Kate";
```

I use sqlite C interface (sqlite3_bind_text() and ? marks while query building) but neither C query nor SQLite Administrator return any data

Comment: Double quotes delimit and identifier.  You need to use single quotes for a string literal.

Comment: it doesn't work in the form of 
SELECT id FROM mediainfo WHERE album='Betty & Kate';
either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`&` is not a special character either in C strings or in SQL strings, so I don't think that's the problem. Try the same query from a tool like [SQLite Database Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: As I said, I've tried the query in SQLite Administrator: http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/ . I don't think SQLite Database Browsert is any different. It seems like I should escape the ampersand sign somehow in the query

Comment: BTW, 
SELECT id FROM mediainfo WHERE album LIKE 'Betty & Kate';
works but it's not exactly what I want.

Comment: Again, <SELECT id FROM mediainfo WHERE album='Betty % Kate'> works too but % is a wildcard character and I want exact match

Comment: Well, that *is* weird! I would create another 2 rows (using your SQLite Administrator), with and without an ampersand, but otherwise the same and test it with that, just to confirm that the ampersand is the problem.

Comment: Sorry my bad. I've mistakenly interchanged "album" column name with "artist"..
But now, got another problem: how to escape single quote character?

Comment: album name is <80's Giga Hits Collection>, don't know how to filter all songs with this album

Comment: to escape it, I had to use two single quotes